# Why does my variable change according to its reference and not the other way round?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference

I am new to C++. With the following minimal program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i, &ri =i;
    i = 5; ri = 10;
    std::cout << i  << " " << ri << std::endl;
}
```

I observe the output to be

```
10 10
```

where I expected it to be

```
5 10
```

My line of reasonning is:

1. `&ri` refers to `i`, so the initial value of `ri` is equal to `i` (whatever that is).
2. Now, when I assign the value 5 to `i`, then the value of `ri` changes to 5.
3. Now, when I change the value of `ri` to 10, then the reference of `ri` to `i` is removed and it now occupies a unique space with the value 10 and is no longer linked to `i`.
4. Therefore, now when I `std::cout << i and << ri`, the result should display `5 10`.

Instead it seems that `i` is referring to `ri` (I checked by changing the values that I assign to `ri`).

Can you please let me know what I am thinking incorrectly?

Comment: Assigning to `ri` changes _what `ri` refers to_, not `ri` itself.  That's what references are for.

Comment: #3 is where you are wrong. ***then the reference of ri to i is removed*** No it still is a reference.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Please, avoid this syntax `int i, &ri =i;` and instead separate each declaration on its own line.

Comment: Even though this is a question about a basic aspect of C++, I think it is an on-topic question. The OP provided an MCVE, the observed behavior and the expected behavior. I've seen far worse. +1

Comment: Think of references as aliases for the variable they refer to. A reference *is* the same as the referenced variable. It's just another name for it.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thanks! This is possibly the most succinct and clear explanation I could get. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ is not java. You cannot reassign a reference.

`ri = 10;` does not create another integer for `ri` to bind to. It is actually changing the value of what `ri` is bound to, which is `i`.

As suggested in the comments, you really should go for [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/5470596).

Comment: Thanks - this is clear. Actually, someone referred me to the link you mentioned and I picked up C++ Primer. I mistakenly left out a couple of lines where this was explained. It was basically my carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

`r` and `ri` simply are two names for the same thing. You first assign `5` to that thing and later `10`. After that, of course that one thing is `10` and referring to it with any of the names will give you that common value.

Answer (score 0):

Reference means that you are assigning a variable `&i` to have the same memory address as the variable you are setting it equal to -- `i`. Thus, changing something about the information at that address changes any variable that is looking at that address for it's value (i.e. a reference or pointer variable).

Answer (score 0):

ri is a reference to i. References work like pointers. ri and i are the same memory. If you type

```
std::cout << &i << "  " << &ri << std::endl;
```

both will be the same. Setting ri to 10 doesn't give it new memory but sets current.